# FFmpeg corrupts videos when using -ss parameter

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to extract middle of a video with ffmpeg. I am using command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:a copy -c:v copy -ss 00:04:20 -t 50 output.mp4
```

I am having different issues with the outputs I get. Sometimes I can't play the whole video at all. Right now the videos I get are out for a few seconds (the sound still is hearable), then they play normally.

Here is the whole thing I get in cmd:

```
E:\Videos>ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a copy -ss 00:04:20 -t 50 output.mp4
ffmpeg version 2022-06-06-git-73302aa193-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11.3.0 (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      57. 26.100 / 57. 26.100
  libavcodec     59. 33.100 / 59. 33.100
  libavformat    59. 24.100 / 59. 24.100
  libavdevice    59.  6.100 / 59.  6.100
  libavfilter     8. 40.100 /  8. 40.100
  libswscale      6.  6.100 /  6.  6.100
  libswresample   4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libpostproc    56.  5.100 / 56.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Duration: 00:08:26.77, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4632 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 4432 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 191 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.24.100
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 4432 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 191 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 1414 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=   33243kB time=00:00:50.01 bitrate=5444.8kbits/s speed= 545x
video:32014kB audio:1177kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.158663%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read this documentation: http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking

Basically if you don't want to reencode (`-c:v copy`) ffmpeg will cut the video stream on keyframes only, which are generally not at the exact desired timestamps. This explains why you have only audio for a few seconds before the video finally shows up.

As for the cases where the output is not playable (corrupted?), I'm not sure. But the behavior of the `-ss` option is different depending if it is before or after `-i`. `-ss` after `-i` means that the input stream is decoded and reencoded until the final desired time: what happens when it is combined with `-c:v copy` is not clear, and I wouldn't use it.

If you really don't want to reencode you should try moving `-ss` before `-i`: you will still have some audio without video at the beginning, but it looks more consistent to me and should fix the "corruption" (or whatever it is) cases. But if you really need to extract the video at a very accurate time (not limited to keyframes) then you have to reencode the streams.